# Opensuse 15.0 and wi-fi don't work

Tags: opensuse

I made the upgrade to 14.3 at 15.0 all the system is perfect but I can't access to wi-fi, I use the password to access on internet, but when I open the browser or download something with cli, I see that internet connection don't work, I have used a live of fedora and internet connection do his work, I leave here one that I have seen when I boot the pc:
Failed to start setup virtual console

Answer (score 1):

Okay i have solve my problems, here the solution:
https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/531935-Most-internet-connectabilities-not-workning
Just use this: netconfig -f update
On cli